# Linker error with intercepting function calls in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, ld, undefined-reference

I am using the standard `__wrap_function` and `__real_function` to intercept function calls with `-Wl,--wrap=function`. This works successfully for most functions like `malloc`, `fopen`, etc. However, I am unable to wrap these two functions:

1. `int connect(int, const struct sockaddr*, socklen_t)`
2. `int stat(const char*, struct stat*)`

With these functions, the linker complains with undefined reference to `__real_connect` and `__real_stat`.

Is there any particular reason for this? (Note: I can also wrap `socket` functions for example)

Comment: Exactly which operating system and C library are you doing this with?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what C compiler and libc you're using. Given your profile picture and the nature of those options, it's reasonably safe to assume gcc and glibc, but better to specify explicitly.

Comment: I am stuck with GCC 4.4.7 and glibc 2.12, Linux kernel 2.6.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you forgot to add `-Wl,--wrap=connect` and `-Wl,--wrap=stat` to your link line.

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int __wrap_connect (int s, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t len)
{
    puts(__func__);
    return __real_connect(s, addr, len);
}

int __wrap_stat (const char *path, struct stat *buf)
{
    puts(__func__);
    return __real_stat(path, buf);
}

int main(void) {
    connect(0, NULL, 0);
    stat("/", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled on my system.

> ```
> $ uname -s -r
> Linux 2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64
> $ gcc --version | grep gcc
> gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
> $ gcc c.c -Wl,--wrap=connect -Wl,--wrap=stat
> $
> ```

However, when leaving off `-Wl,--wrap=stat`, for example, I get:

> ```
> $ gcc c.c -Wl,--wrap=connect
> /tmp/cchVzvsE.o: In function `__wrap_stat':
> c.c:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `__real_stat'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> $
> ```

Comment: It seems like something to do with my cmake files. Clearing cache and running cmake . and then make resolved the issue! But at the core, yes, if I miss the linker line, it will be an undefined reference! Thank you for the help.

Comment: @a_pradhan: Since my answer did not actually address your issue, you should go ahead and update your question with the specifics of your problem. Then, author an answer that resolves the specific issues raised in your updated question. This will increase the relevancy of your question and answer to future readers. I will leave my answer up just for additional information (I already made it a community wiki answer since I didn't have any confidence it would address your specific problem).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error was caused due to cmake issues. Clearing the cmake cache and running cmake . followed by make all resolved it.